# Sort string data as Int in jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables, columnsorting

I have string Data in my `ProviderQualificationTime` field.So it doesn't sort this column properly since the data is a `string`. How can I make the `datatable` to treat it as `Int` Column and sort according to that?
Possible?
Sample Data in `ProviderQualificationTime` field:

> "1","10","11","NotAccpeted"

Code:

```
$('#tblProviders').dataTable({
                            "autoWidth": false,
                            "searching": false,
                            "pageLength": 6,
                            "lengthMenu": [6, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
                            "bDestroy": true,
                            data: obj.data.ProviderQualificationDetails,
                            columns: [
                                       { "data": "ProviderName" },
                                       { "data": "ProviderQualificationTime" },
                                       { "data": "TotalServiceableOffers" }
                            ]
                        });
```

Comment: `data : obj.data.ProviderQualificationDetails.map(Number),`

Comment: @adeneo will it not convert the whole `ProviderQualificationDetails`
object into number? I just want `ProviderQualificationTime` to be of type number.

Comment: Then I guess you'd have to figure out how to map it and convert only the index you want to a number

Comment: Also `ProviderQualificationDetails` is a array

Answer (score 1):

I would use a columnDef object to specify a render function like so:

```
$('#tblProviders').dataTable({
 "autoWidth": false,
 "searching": false,
 "pageLength": 6,
 "lengthMenu": [6, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
 "bDestroy": true,
 data: obj.data.ProviderQualificationDetails,
 columns: [
   { "data": "ProviderName" },
   { "data": "ProviderQualificationTime" },
   { "data": "TotalServiceableOffers" }
 ],
 "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 1,
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
       // If this is a display render request ...
       if(type === 'display') {
         // don't modify it.
         return data;
       }

       // Either convert it to a number if it is a numeric value or set it to 0
       // This will return a numeric value for sorting and filtering.
       return (isNaN(data)) ? 0 : +data;
    }
 }]
});
```

So with the custom renderer for your column you can have a unmodified display value and a converted sort/filter value.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5 data attributes you can specify data-order. This will allow the datatable to order the content differently from the data that is actually displayed:
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

For example:

```
<td data-order='0'>NotAccepted</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly but works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "numNonStandard-asc": function (a, b) {
      var x = isNaN(parseInt(a, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(a, 10);
      var y = isNaN(parseInt(b, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(b, 10);
      return (x == y) ? 0 : (x < y) ? 1 : -1;
    },
    "numNonStandard-desc": function (a, b) {
      var x = isNaN(parseInt(a, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(a, 10);
      var y = isNaN(parseInt(b, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(b, 10);
      return (x == y) ? 0 : (x < y) ? -1 : 1;
    }
  });
  $('.table-data').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
      { type: 'numNonStandard', targets: -1 }
    ]
  });
});
```

Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/t67das7o/).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the given below parameter:

`"sType": "string"`

For more details visit the link [https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24284/column-sort-wrong-data-always-string]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/signed-num

and in first IF condition that is **return (a=="-" || a==="") ? 0 : a.replace('+','')*1;** add one more or condition like (a == "-" || a === "" **|| a == "NotAccpeted"**) ? 0 : a.replace('+', '') * 1;